# self.tableView reloadData not working after successful call in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking, reloaddata

I have a class that runs similar to the AFHTTPSessionManager component of this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

However, [self.tableView reloadData] is not working for me.

I have the manager implemented as so:

```
-(void) refresh{
     manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager...] iniwithBaseURL:...];
     [manager Get:... parameters:... success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject){
         //test success values in responseObject
         if(test){
             //Get table data
             [self.tableView reloadData];
         }
     }
     ....
}
```

However if I run [self.tableView reloadData] in a separate function afterwards, it works just fine. 
Why is this happening, instead of how it should in the tutorial?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

write the `[self.tableView reloadData];`in the main queue.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: Don't repeat answers.

Comment: actually, this one came first. so im giving it the checkmark

Comment: No mine was first but thats okay

Comment: I guess I will just give as many upvotes as I reasonably can then :P

Comment: Dont worry about it, most important is your problem is solved

Comment: This isn't a duplicate answer. One calls for dispatch_ASYNC the other for dispatch_SYNC, very different.

Answer (score 40):

Always reload on the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: I find it odd that I would need this for reloadData, but it isn't necessary in another instance of AFHTTPSessionManager where I have viewControllers perform segues in the success block